# Laravel on sub folder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to install `Laravel 5.3` in sub domain `/public_html/mysite` 
but it's not working should I change `.htaccess` or what ?

Comment: what dir is the subdomain pointing at?

Comment: It's `mysite` folder , I've tried the answer below it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the content of `public` (L5) directly on `public_html` (be aware of don't overwrite the `.htaccess` file accidentally) Now in then modify your `index.php` and your `bootstrap.php` and it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I hope @Nino Armani gave you the right answer. Although you can try with visual video tutorial here-
http://www.tisuchi.com/upload-laravel-projecy-cpanel/

Answer (score 0):

- Move everything from **project/public** folder to **project/** folder
- Update index.php to have bootstrap path like "./bootstrap"
- Add base APP_URL in your .env
- Update layout folder paths like {{URL::to('/css/app.css')}}